# who can help me eyeball this small piece of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few lines of code which seems pretty simple, but just doing something unexpected, appreciate if you could eyeball it for me and give me a hint.

there are two console.log in the code and the output of them are in the picture attached, the first log shows they are holding some values, and the second suggests that they don't ( assignment doesn't work), just can't see how those lines in between could affect.

notes: some commented lines in between have been removed for clearity.

```
  const { password, confirmPassword, role, position, ...rest } = this.state.data
  console.log(role.value, position.value)
  let dataToSave
  if (this.state.isPasswordChanged) {
      dataToSave = { password, roleID: role.value, positionId: position.value, ...rest 
  }
  else {
        dataToSave = { roleID: role.value, positionId: position.value, ...rest }
  }
  console.log(dataToSave)
```

[image]

Comment: this may happen if `rest` having `positionId :null` , can you try keeping the `rest` at the begening? like this:
`dataToSave = { ...rest,roleID: role.value, positionId: position.value }`

Comment: can you please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ujsnlg , and can you check position.value is not null.  In the link demonstrated your data and it's working fine.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty, you are right, it does, don't know how I missed it, maybe too late, brain stopped, :(, don't know to kudo you for just comment, but thanks a lot)

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps I might normally like to write this proposed observation as a comment but I still need a higher reputation score to be able to write comments.)

I don't see how "5c4459e47afe0821c4790637" shows that position.value ever had a value, and I'm thinking that it never did and you need to find out why.